# How to get username of a user just by using their stored id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I get the username and discriminator of someone just by using their id? I have user ids that are stored in a mysql database and I need to take them out and display those user's usernames.

Like `var username = ('user-id').username`

I know there is a fetchUser function however it does not work with the newer version of discord.js. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetchUser still works it was just moved

```
client.users.fetch(id).then(user => {
    console.log(user.username);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it `<client>.users.cache.get("User_ID").tag`

Comment: Actually to get the username and discriminator replace `.username` with `.tag`